# What are the additional privileges earned by an elder?

Tags: clash-royale

I've noticed that clan Members might get promoted to Elders, due to a certain number of donations reached, or something like that.
**What are the (general) privileges earned by Elders?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elders are the first level of promotion. They are able to kick members and invite or accept players to the Clan, but are not viable to change the Clan Settings.
[Source](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Clans)